# If the tensor power $M^{\otimes n} = 0$, is it possible that $M^{\otimes n-1}$ is nonzero?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

This question was asked earlier on math.stackexchange: [click here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/737003/if-the-tensor-power-m-otimes-n-0-is-it-possible-that-m-otimes-n-1-i). See the comments and the answer by Jack Schmidt there.

Let $M$ be a module over a commutative ring $R$.

It is possible that $M \otimes M = 0$ if $M$ is nonzero, for example when $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $M = \mathbb{Q}/ \mathbb{Z}$.

What about when higher tensor powers of $M$ are zero? If $M \otimes M \otimes M = 0$, is it possible that $M \otimes M$ is nonzero? More generally if $M^{\otimes n} = 0$ for $n \geq 3$, is it possible that $M^{\otimes n-1}$ is nonzero?

The answer by Jack Schmidt in the math.stackexchange question shows that the answer to these questions is no, in the case of $R = \mathbb{Z}$, ie. in the case of abelian groups. Quote from his answer:

> **Theorem:** If $M$ is an abelian group with $M \otimes M \otimes M = 0$, then $M$ is a divisible torsion abelian group and $M \otimes M = 0$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My previous attempt was completely wrong, as Jason Starr politely pointed out.

But I think the idea I was grasping for does work, in this example:

Let $R=k[x,y]$ for a field $k$, and let
$$M=\frac{k[x,y,y^{-1}]}{k[x,y]}\oplus\frac{k[x,x^{-1},y]}{k[x,y]}.$$

[So that Jason's comment still makes sense, I'll leave my previous stupid wrong answer:

How about $R=\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ and $M=(\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z})\oplus(\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$?]

Comment: That doesn't work.  There is a surjective homomorphism to $R=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$, namely multiplication by $(0,1)$ on the first summand plus multiplication by $(1,0)$ on the second summand.  Since tensor product over $R$ is right exact, for every integer $n>0$, there is a surjectiction $M^{\otimes n} \to R^{\otimes n} = R$.

Comment: @JasonStarr: You're quite right, of course. I was being stupid. But I think the idea I was trying to make into an example does work, and I've edited my answer.

Comment: I believe the new example works.  By using $n$ variables instead of $2$ variables, you should also get a module $M$ such that $M^{\otimes n}$ is nonzero, yet $M^{\otimes(n+1)}$ is zero.